# Pyqt5 Как открыть .exe файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Я хочу открыть `.exe` файл через програму на *PyQt5*. Нажимаю жду не запускается что делать ?

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
from design import Ui_MainWindow

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Roblox.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

    def btnClicked(self):
        f = open('Roblox.exe')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```
import sys
import subprocess                                                 # +++
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
#from design import Ui_MainWindow

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

#        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#        self.ui.setupUi(self)
#        self.ui.Roblox.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        Roblox = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Roblox")
        Roblox.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(Roblox)


    def btnClicked(self):
#        f = open('C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe')
        exePath = "C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe"                        # +++
        subprocess.Popen(exePath)                                       # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = MyWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile):

```
...
    def btnClicked(self):
        os.startfile('calc.exe')
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import win32api
win32api.WinExec('show_web_browser.exe')
```

- for Windows OS

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж тут пошли разные варианты то вот еще:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe"])
```

```
import os
os.system(r'"C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe"')
```

И для мака если на то пошло:

```
import os
os.system("""osascript -e 'tell app "SomeApp" to open'""")
```

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(
    ["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/TextEdit.app"]
)
```

Большое количество разных вариантов здесь:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845242/how-to-open-an-application-in-mac-os-using-python